# Is this a hashed database ID?

Tags: database, security, hash

I inherited a project, and I'm trying to understand the variables and IDs that appear like such:

749E8-DEBBD-4BAB7-6E3D2

Are these hashed database IDs?  Given the structure, is there a way to understand how they were generated?

Comment: Looks like an 80-bit (4 x 20) value in hexa.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I couldn't find that on a Google search.  Could you share some more info?

Comment: I'm only looking at the value. It's separated by dashes in four sections. Each section is a 5-char value. Each char seems to be an hexa char since it includes digits and letters (A, B, D, E). Since an hexa char can store 4 bits, each section can store 20 bits (5 x 4). Then, the whole string can store 80 bits (4 x 20). To me it looks like the IDs you would find in scratch cards for Microsoft/Steam products or for gifts cards (but this is just a guess).